# Shopify: Amazon Style Cart Page

Tags: ajax, json, shopify

Looked everywhere on the site before posting and couldn't find an answer.

What I'm looking for is to have a cart page pretty much exactly like Amazon's.

Where once a customer adds a product to the cart, they're redirected and a success message appears at the top saying "X Product Has Been Added To Cart!" - next to the product's image that was recently added and pulled with it.

And when a customer adds another product, the only thing that changes is the cart total (which would also be at the top next to the success message) and the image of the product.

So the cart doesn't actually build vertically, the items are just added along with a success message at the top.

I know there's AJAX involved in this but after 25 hours of fruitless attempts, I've literally got nothing to show.

The closest thing I found to this question was related to the success message, but I still didn't get it:

[Shopify post Ajax add to cart success message on Cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994239/shopify-post-ajax-add-to-cart-success-message-on-cart-page?rq=1)

If anyone knows how to do this or at least point me in a clear direction, I would love you!!

Comment: using javascript and jquery you can add,update,and delete the shopify cart. Try with the manual cart.js: http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api

Comment: what you want to do is possible but it would require some substantial editing of cart.liquid as well as some javascript to switch between what you are proposing and an edit cart/standard cart.liquid function. If you're really good with css layout  and can pass something in the url to trigger javascript to show/hide the different versions of the cart then you can make this happen. if not you'll have to hire someone as this isn't a small job, especially since you haven't shown us any of your work to go on.